# Read wordpress Export XML with nodeJS

Tags: json, xml, node.js, wordpress

i want to read read the Wordpress Export XML with nodejs to JSON.
After i am done with the manipulation of the data i want to import it to Wordpress. So i need to convert json to XML.

I tried different npm script, but nothing working out of the box.

I have read the documentation on Wordpress that is is using

> This format, which is called and WordPress eXtended RSS or WXR file

So how can i solve this problem?

Exampel of what i tried before.

```
var oldprice = req.files['oldprice'].buffer.toString();
var json = xml2json.toJson(oldprice);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this lib. Dont know way it wouldn't work with the other...
https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js